# Showing $\hat{\tilde{f}}=\tilde{\hat{f}}$ where $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform, and $\tilde{f}(x) = f(-x)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I'm trying to prove that $\hat{\tilde{f}}=\tilde{\hat{f}}$ for any integrable function $f$, where $\hat{f}$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$ and $\tilde{f}$ denotes the mapping $f(x)\to f(-x)$, though I'm currently stuck at $$\hat{\tilde{f}}(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(-t)e^{-2\pi it\cdot x}dt\tag*{(1)}$$ and $$\tilde{\hat{f}}(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(t)e^{2\pi it\cdot x}dt\tag*{(2)}.$$ Surely the substitution $u=-t$ in $(1)$ gives $$\hat{\tilde{f}}(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}-f(u)e^{2\pi iu\cdot x}du,$$ which in general is not equal to $(2)$? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful when doing the change of variables. The differentials change by the *absolute value* of the determinant of the Jacobian of the transformation, which in this case is $|(-1)^n| = 1$.

You can see your error if you write your integrals as iterated integrals. Write $\hat{\tilde{f}}(x)$ as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(-t)e^{-2\pi it\cdot x}dt_1\dots dt_n$. Then the variable substitution $u = -t$ corresponds to the $n$ variable substitutions $u_k = - t_k$. For each $k$ we see that $du_k = -dt_k$, but also, the limits of integration swap. That is,

\begin{align*}
\hat{\tilde{f}}(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(-t)e^{-2\pi it\cdot x}dt_1\dots dt_n\\ 
&= \int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\dots\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}f(u)e^{2\pi iu\cdot x}(-1)^ndu_1\dots du_n\\ 
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^nf(u)e^{2\pi iu\cdot x}(-1)^ndu_1\dots du_n\\ 
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(u)e^{2\pi iu\cdot x}|(-1)^n|du_1\dots du_n\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(u)e^{2\pi iu\cdot x}du_1\dots du_n\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(u)e^{2\pi iu\cdot x}du.
\end{align*}

Replacing $u$ by $t$, you then obtain $\hat{\tilde{f}}(x) = \tilde{\hat{f}}(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $g\in L^1(\Bbb R^d)$ then $$\int_{\Bbb R^d}g(-t)\,dt=\int_{\Bbb R^d}g(t)\,dt.\quad(*)$$Note the minus sign you think should be there is missing; erase it from what you've done on your problem and you're done.

Of course this raises the question of why the extra minus sign is there in Calc I but not here. Before getting into that, you should prove (*) from the definitions, starting with $g=\chi_E$.

And you should note that an extra minus sign in (*) would make no sense if the integral is the "area under the graph"; the change of variables doesn't change the sign of that area.

And now we begin to suspect that Calc I is wrong. No, the point is just that antiderivatives are not integrals. Say $F'=f$ (in one variable, and ignoring little details like convergence). Then $-F(-t)$ is an antiderivative for $f(-t)$. There's the extra minus sign. But it goes away again when we look at the *integral*: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(-t)=-\int_\infty^{-\infty}f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t).$$

Which is to say Calc I agrees with (*), it just doesn't look that way because of the emphasis on antiderivatives instead of integrals.